# Consequences of not following the mitzvoths

Tags: reward-punishment, heterodox, noachide-laws, faith-bitachon-emunah, ikarim

My question is, “ If a person who has right belief in the oneness of Hashem,  and he believes that the Torah is word of G-d, and all the prophets are true and he believes in the Divine judgment and final reward and punishments and he believes in the olam haba and he believes in the all the angels and predestination and all the books and he believes in the shewa mitzvets of Noach, and he condemn the avodo zarah, but he do not keep any other mitzovets , then “ what is the benefits of his genuine belief and what are the consequences of not following the mitzovets”.?.
“Is there any benefits of his genuine belief?.”  “Will he have any portion in olam haba?.”.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking specifically about a non-Jew, right?

Comment: "Predestination"? Are you referring to the Calvinist doctrine or the like? Because that is at odds with traditional Judaism.

Comment: @ HodofHod: I am asking as a non Jew.

Comment: @ Fred : it is not Calvinist doctrine but it is like that.

Comment: @ Fred: it is not Calvinist doctrine but it is like that, but it is like pre programmed computer video game, i do believe in free will and this predestination is just exactly as a programmed video game, in case of the video game every act of the player is pre programmed but its out come depends on the skill of the player and its player has free will but the visual graphics and the fighting scenes and victory and defeat scenes all are pre programmed. I mean this type of predestination, not as the calvinistic doctrine, I think this type of predestination is not at all at odds with judaism.

Answer (score 4):

A non-Jew who keeps the seven Noahide laws because they were commanded by Moses has a share in the world to come. As a non-Jew, he is not commanded to keep the other mitzvot.

Source: Maimonides, Mishneh Torah, Laws of Kings (Hilkhot Melakhim) 8:11.

Answer (score 1):

After enumerating the list of thirteen principles, Rambam writes:

> וכאשר יהיו קיימים לאדם כל היסודות הללו ואמונתו בהם אמתית הרי הוא נכנס בכלל ישראל וחובה לאהבו ולחמול עליו וכל מה שצוה ה' אותנו זה על זה מן האהבה והאחוה ואפילו עשה מה שיכול להיות מן העבירות מחמת תאותו והתגברות יצרו הרע הרי הוא נענש לפי גודל מריו ויש לו חלק והוא מפושעי ישראל וכאשר יפקפק אדם ביסוד מאלו היסודות הרי זה יצא מן הכלל וכפר בעיקר ונקרא מין ואפיקורות וקוצץ בנטיעות וחובה לשנותו ועליו הוא אומר הלא משנאיך ה' אשנא וכו
>
> (Qafih translation)
>
> And when a person upholds all these foundations, and his belief in them is true, he enters into the group of Israel and it is an obligation to love him, and to have compassion for him, and all that Hashem commanded us regarding love and brotherhood for each other. **And even if he has done what can be of the sins due to his desires and the overpowerment of his evil inclination, he will be punished commensurate to the greatness of his rebellion but he still has a portion and he is of the sinners of Israel.** But when a person doubts one of these foundations he has left the group, and denied God, and is called a sectarian and a heretic and a cutter of shoots, and it is an obligation to hate him, and of him it is said "do I not hate those who hate you, Hashem?"
>
> (My translation and emphasis)

Answer (score -1):

If someone believes the Torah is the word of God, and believes he will be punished for violating it, yet he keeps nothing, then his actions contradict his stated beliefs. His beliefs are not genuine, they have no benefit, and he will not get any Olam Haba for them.

Comment: Editing in a source for your claim would add much value to your answer.

Comment: @ Binyamin: although his actions contradict his beliefs, but his (Emuna) belief in hashem is genuine, he could not do the mitzovot, but he feels guily in the heart, my question is "will his genuine belief will rescue him from the gehannom or not".

Comment: Ishrat, are you asking concerning a Jew or a non-Jew?

Comment: @ joshua Lee: I am asking as a non Jew.